# how to overlay an iframe on your google search?

Tags: javascript, php, html

what I want to do is overlay an iframe on top of my google searches on my browser.
So basically when I search through google for something it also searches through my One note notebook, or my google drive (side by side). without having to copy and paste the same keyword again.

[image]

I tried using a simple iframe to display both the searches by just adding my google search keyword in front of http://www.google.com/search?q=  and the same for searching through google drive (https://drive.google.com/drive/search?q=machine+learning) and one-note in the second iframe but the iframe doesnt render (since google doesn't allow that)

Essentially what I want to do is search through 2 websites at once side by side and not having to type the search keyword again and again inside both the websites. as you would have to do if the websites are running on different tabs.

Comment: Maybe look into creating a Chrome extension that communicates what you’re typing in the search field between different tabs ?